# the instruction at 0x403020 referenced memory at 0x403020. the memory could not be executed ida

Tags: reverse-engineering

I am trying to test below shellcode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memoryapi.h>

unsigned char sc[] = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x41\x41\x41\x41\x54\xbb\x54\x26\x40\x00\xff\xd3\x83\xc4\x04\xc3\x66\x90\x66\x90\x66\x90\x66\x90\x66\x90\x66\x90";
int main()
{
    ((void(*)())sc)();
    return 0;
}
```

The shellcode is just suppose to print `AAAA`.

Directly executing my shellcode doesn't do anything. After debugging it with IDA I realized that the program crashes with below error while trying to execute shellcode.

> 403020: The instruction at 0x403020 referenced memory at 0x403020. The memory could not be executed -> 00403020 (exc.code c00000005, tid 91140)

shellcode segment in IDA:

```
.data:00403020 public _sc
.data:00403020 _sc:                                    ; CODE XREF: _main+10p
[EAX here] .data:00403020                                         ; DATA XREF: _main+Bo
[EIP here] .data:00403020 xor     eax, eax
.data:00403022 push    eax
.data:00403023 push    offset unk_41414141
.data:00403028 push    esp
.data:00403029 mov     ebx, offset _malloc
.data:0040302E call    ebx ; _malloc
.data:00403030 add     esp, 4
.data:00403033 retn
```

My EIP never get to execute `xor eax, eax` and prompts above error.

I have disable DEP in my windows 10.

I also tried to change the permissions of that segment using IDC `SetSegmentAttr(0x00403000, SEGATTR_PERM, 4 | 1 | 2);` and the permission for this segment of memory is below:

```
WINDBG>!vprot 0x403020
BaseAddress:       00403000
AllocationBase:    00400000
AllocationProtect: 00000080  PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
RegionSize:        00001000
State:             00001000  MEM_COMMIT
Protect:           00000004  PAGE_READWRITE
Type:              01000000  MEM_IMAGE
403020: The instruction at 0x403020 referenced memory at 0x403020. The memory could not be executed -    > 00403020 (exc.code c0000005, tid 9140)
```

I have compiled the program as following:

```
gcc -g testshellcode.c -o testshellcode.exe -fno-stack-protector -m32
```

Can someone point me to what is wrong here?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but does changing the signature to `static unsigned char sc` change anything? How about adding `volatile`?

Comment: @RandomDavis changed nothing :(